# Django related key of the same model

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a feature for an app much like a Twitter Retweet.

In the model for `Item`, I want to add a related field for `reposted_from` that will reference another `Item`. I dont think I use `ForeignKey` for this, since it's the same Model, but what do I use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is common to add a [foreign key to self](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) as such:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

You may specify a [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) as such:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')
```

Because an Item may not have a parent, don't forget null=True and blank=True as such:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you will be able to query children as such:

```
item.children
```

You might as well use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) and benefit of some optimization and extra tree features:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Item(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ForeignKey to self. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score -1):

You would use foregein key in the same model if and only if you use string.

```
class Item(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey("reposted_from")

class reposted_from(models.Model):
  repost_from = models.CharField(max_length=122)
```

for example.

Otherwise, you will get undefined reference.
Is that what you need?

Comment: I don't think that works. As you can see the FK constructor signature is class ForeignKey(othermodel[, **options]). So unless "reposted_from" is the name of another model, this won't work https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey